# How to export a H2O learned model to PMML

Tags: export, h2o, pmml

We have learned some models in H2O and want to export the models into PMML.
This is needed to feed the learned model into another running platform.

Has anyone a suggestion in how to do this?

Thnx

Jan

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported path in H2O to do this.  (If anyone in the community has a way, I'd be interested to see it.)

They way H2O provides to productionize models is by exporting them as MOJOs or POJOs.

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/index.html
- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html
- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html